# associativity on elliptic curves -- Milne's proof

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry

In the proof that the group law on an Elliptic curve is associative, Milne (http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf, page 28) sets up 3 cubics,
and claims that they all contain the $8$ points $O,P,Q,R,PQ,QR,P+Q,Q+R$ where $AB$ denotes the third point of intersection on $L(A,B) \cap C$. His cubics are

1. $C = 0$ ($C$ is our elliptic curve.
2. $L(P,Q) \cdot L(R,P+Q) \cdot L(QR,O) = 0$

and
3. $L(P,QR) \cdot L(Q,R) \cdot L(P,O) = 0$

where $L(A,B)$ is the (projective) line determined by $A$ and $B$.

I get why the first two points contains all $8$ points. Why does the last one contain all of them? Maybe there's a typo somewhere, and he meant some other cubic for 3?

edit 1: so obviously $O,P,Q,R,QR$ are on the third line. Why are the other $3$ points on that cubic?

edit 2: I'm starting to think that there is a typo in Milne's book. Either way, I have found another line containing all $8$ points, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this looks like a typo – or even two. Consider the illustration on that same page:

[image: Illustration from the book]

Apparently the last cubic should be

$$L(P,Q\color{red}{+}R)\cdot L(Q,R)\cdot L(P\color{red}{Q},O)=0$$

or something along these lines. It corresponds to the three horizontal lines in that illustration, just like the second cubic correctly corresponds to the vertical ones.

The [errata document](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/eccorrections.doc) does not mention this problem. You might consider contacting the author about this.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I'll consider contacting the author about this.